# How to sum a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, sum, linear-algebra

Let `A = np.ones([3,3,5])`.

Is there any linear algebra operation which will return
`array([[ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.]])` without any looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A.sum(axis=(0, 1))
```

Call the standard `sum` routine with a tuple of axes to sum over.